# How do I see provisioning profiles for sideloaded apps on iPad?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipados, configuration-profiles

I have developer versions of 2 of my own apps running on my iPad under OS version 15.6.1.  I would like to be able to check the expiry date of the provisioning profiles without going to my development computer and running Xcode.

Web searches tell me to look in "Settings - General - Device Management" or "Settings - General - Profiles" or similar names of locations, but those don't seem to exist for this version.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of iOS / iPadOS exposing the details of provisioning profiles, but there's no reason you couldn't use mobile safari to look it up if you need to from the device.

- https://developer.apple.com/help/account/manage-profiles/create-a-development-provisioning-profile

Unless you need to log the [intermediate self generated certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50247348/how-do-i-change-provision-profile-on-xcode) in Xcode - you may need to keep your Xcode [accessible remotely (I use Screens](https://edovia.com/en/screens-ios/) and [Screens Connect](https://edovia.com/en/screens-connect/)) to get back to my Mac if I don't have a VPN tunnel back home set up. You could [make a custom build script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75186998/475228) / steps to dump the values and save it to a text file or [have the app display the results](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/certificates/examining_a_certificate) of the build like a build version but that seems like an extreme amount of work for something you could look up with a network connection if needed.

Comment: It has been available in the past under one or another Settings subsection.  For some odd reason, Apple moves it every few releases.  I'm beginning to think that the move on this version was to "away".

Comment: Agreed - it's clearly not where it logically should be shown by iOS / iPadOS at present @PhillipMills